# How to use data from reqres.in with javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Probally stupid question, but i cant get it working using AJAX examples that i have used before.

**TASK**

I have task to read data from [here](https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=10). And i have to use javascript or AJAX.

First how do i read it to get all the information as it is?

Secondly i get that it's in JSON format, how do i use it? For example when i want to loop over every user and get only first_name and last_name?

Thank you for answering!

**EDIT**

Ajax that i have used before to get data from same server:

```
    $.get("ajax_info.html",function(data){
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = data;
    });
```

Also i have used https://crossorigin.me, to get webpage html which is not in my domain.

Comment: let us see your ajax that you've worked before.

Comment: Edited my post @Roljhon

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve your requirements by using jQuery ajax(). Below is an working example. Hope it helps.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=10",
    data: {},
    beforeSend: function(){}
}).done(function(response) {
    var trArr = new Array();
    $.each(response.data, function(i, v){
     trArr.push('<tr><td>' + v.id + '</td><td>' + v.first_name + '</td><td>' + v.last_name + '</td><td><img src="' + v.avatar + '" width="120px" /></td></tr>');
    });
    $('table#alk-table tbody').append(trArr.join('\n'));
});
```

```css
table#alk-table tr th {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="alk-table" border="1">
  <thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Avatar</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using jQuery, pretty easy.

```js
$.ajax(
{
url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=10",
method: "get",
dataType: "json"
}).done(function(res){
  res.data.map((item)=>
  {
    console.log(item.first_name + " "+ item.last_name)
  });
});;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**OR** using VanillaJS

```js
function reqListener () {
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  jsonResponse.data.map( (item) => {
    console.log(item.first_name + " "+item.last_name);
  })
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET","https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=10");
oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
oReq.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is get it using jquery ajax and then iterate of the results:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=10",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result.data, function(index, value) { 
        var myName = value.first_name + " " + value.last_name;
        $("#Names").append("<div>" + myName + "</div>");
      });
    }
  })
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1977yphL/1/) of it working: